# EmberData Model-Definition Changes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been using EmberModel in a working application for awhile, and now want to move back to using EmberData.  I noticed from the "Model Guide" documentation on the Ember website that the proper way of defining a hasMany relationship in an EmberData model has changed.  In earlier versions of EmberData, I defined my models like this:

```
 App.StratItem = DS.Model.extend({
   id: DS.attr('string),
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   quantity: DS.attr('number'),
   type: DS.attr('string'),
   strategy: DS.belongsTo('strat')
 });

 App.Strat = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('string'),
    stratName: DS.attr('string'),
    sDate: DS.attr('number'),
    eDate: DS.attr('number'),
    stratItems: DS.hasMany('stratItem',{async:true})
 });
```

If I interpret the current documentations correctly, the correct definition for the same models now should be:

```
 App.StratItem = DS.Model.extend({
   id: DS.belongsTo('strat')
   name: DS.belongsTo('strat')
   quantity: DS.belongsTo('strat')
   type: DS.belongsTo('strat')
 });

 App.Strat = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr(),
    stratName: DS.attr(),
    sDate: DS.attr(),
    eDate: DS.attr(),
    stratItems: DS.hasMany('stratItem')
 });
```

Here are my questions:

1) Is my interpretation of the documentation correct?

2) If yes, what's the purpose of specifying "belongsTo" for every variable in "StratItem" while I've already specified in 'Strat' that the entire 'StratItem' model (i.e., all variables) is a child of 'Strat'?

3) Is {async:true} still necessary?

I'm getting an "error while loading route" error message from Ember on code that used to work with older versions of Ember (version 1.0 rc) and Ember Data; the above changes are the only ones I made so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got confused, but you should not be defining a `belongsTo` relationship for attributes:

```
App.StratItem = DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr(),
   quantity: DS.attr(),
   type: DS.attr(),
   strategy: DS.belongsTo('strat')
 });

 App.Strat = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr(),
    stratName: DS.attr(),
    sDate: DS.attr(),
    eDate: DS.attr(),
    stratItems: DS.hasMany('stratItem')
 });
```

`id: DS.attr(),` is unnecessary. Ember data does this automatically.

`{async:true}` is only necessary if you're not sideloading your related data.

Comment: Please take a look at the "Explicit Inverses" section in the Ember Guide for 'Models' http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/

It seems to indicate that I need to specify "belongsTo" in the attributes - doesn't it?

Comment: That's only if you have multiple multiple `belongsTo/hasManys` for the same type. You have one of each.

Comment: That section in the documentation really confuses me.  Are onePost, twoPost, redPost, and bluePost mentioned in the documentation attributes of App.Comment?

Comment: They are additional relationships of `comment`. A contrived example would be a `child` belongsTo `mother` and `father`. The `mother` hasMany children (with the inverse set explicitly to be `mother`)